# Wrong output with search function SQL

Tags: php, sql, string, output

I have tried to connect a metadata tag to a user, I got the relationship between them but when I search the tag I get a large output. I have a tag named Chips, but the output is 17 different users. None of them have nothing todo with the word or the tag.

**To clearify what I'm trying todo:**
I'm making a search function that can search for username, motto and tag.
http://gyazo.com/d334447761152394ca1eecc392c35e92

```
<?php

    $varr = preg_replace("/%u([0-9a-f]{3,4})/i","&#x\\1;",urldecode($url)); 
    $varr = html_entity_decode($url,null,'UTF-8');

    $query = $_GET['query']; 
    $min_length = 2;

    if(strlen($query) >= $min_length){ 

    $query = htmlspecialchars($query); 
    $query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);

    $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users, user_tags
                WHERE (`username` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`tag` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`motto` LIKE '%".$query."%')") or die(mysql_error());
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($raw_results);
?>
```

Comment: There must be a matching word `Chips` thats why results are returned :P

Comment: What is the relation between them?

Comment: They have a connection because of the user_id. I thought it wouldnt return anything if the word didnt match. It should only match the tag, because none of the users are named ch, chi, chip, chips in their name.

Comment: Please be aware that the mysql_ functions are now no longer just discouraged (as it was over the last years), but officially [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php). You should really use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php), as this code will stop working very soon. See [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT *
FROM users, user_tags
WHERE . . .
```

The problem has nothing to do with your `WHERE` clause.  It is the comma in the `FROM`.  Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use explicit `JOIN` syntax.

The correct syntax looks more like this (but depends on your column names):

```
SELECT *
FROM users u JOIN
     user_tags ut
     ON u.userId = ut.userId
WHERE . . .
```